# DevTools in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.5, devtools

I am using vue.js inside Laravel 5.5.33 (not SPA). I am getting below error.

[image]

How can I enable DevTools?

Comment: What was the solution to your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you have this setting in your app.js file

```js
Vue.config.devtools = true
```

If you are using mix, check the dist of vue in webpack.mix, be sure you don't use min version

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'
            }
        }
    });
```

Run your npm in dev

```sh
npm run watch
```

**WARNING**
If you refresh your page in your browser, the cache is not refreshed. Clean the cache to reload the app.js

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue when production grade build is used.

> You are probably using Vue from CDN, and probably using a production build (dist/vue.min.js). Either replace it with a dev build (dist/vue.js) or add Vue.config.devtools = true to the main js file.

Check out the github [`link`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/190).

Answer (score 0):

But, for me, the problem with DevTools was solved just when I put the line that is provided in the answer below after creating your Vue application.

Your code should look like this

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data () {
   text: 'testData'
 }
})

Vue.config.devtools = true
```