# Vue DevTools inspection is not available

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-devtools

Im using laravel 5.2

Package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.14",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "get-ssl-certificate": "^2.1.2",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0"
  }
}
```

I tried both firefox and google chrome extension which says its disabled
This is the line that restrict this

```
   devtools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
```

to my two sense this must NOT happen.
Steps I took till now :

1- remove node_models install it again using npm install

2- replacing the vue file with a version provided in Vuejs.org

the icon is there colorful but no Veo devtool, when i use CDN on top of my header instead i get the devtools!
What is causing this conflict! Im confused
thanks for any help

Comment: What does the icon say when you click on it? Does it say something along the lines of `Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode...`?

Comment: Can you provide your main.js?

Comment: look here, it's the same issue I think :
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56881260/8756956)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay long story short the problem caused because  it was not compiling my files and devmode was off in the version it was complied before.
I was trying to use vue on laravel 5.2 , faced many problems so i decided to **install**
laravel 5.3 by :

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myapp "5.3.0"
```

after that I executed :

```
  npm install
```

and it started to install the dependencies and all , when it was done I tested **gulp** command to see if its a success compile which it was. so I moved **package.json** **package-lock.json** and **gulpfile.js** from my Laravel 5.3 to laravel 5.2 run npm install again and all Done!